# Clear icon is missing HTML5 input type=search with ASP.NET MVC and Bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap, input

I am working on an MVC application and would like to add an X for clearing current search criteria to my search box - like the one that comes by default with using input type=search in html5: [image]
<sub>(source: [html5tutorial.info](https://html5tutorial.info/images/input_type_search.png))</sub>

Below you can see my current code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search by Author or Title" })
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it in the `htmlAttributes`

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string,
    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search by Author", @type= "search" })
```

If you're using bootstrap, this icon won't be displayed ([issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5624)). There is a workaround. Add the following style to override default bootstrap styles:

```
<style>
    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
        /*Bootstrap 3 override*/
        -webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button !important;
    }
</style>
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8jcPZo

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Note that this stops working when I add bootstrap: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8UtRVA Even if I don't use any classes per se. Just by doing the import. There seems to be a compatibility issue between the two - any suggestions how one could get around that?

Comment: apparently this is an [issue with bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5624). Updated the answer and the fiddle with a [workaround](https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/issues/161).

Comment: The style hack does indeed bring back the x button, but clicking on it only clears the search box. How can I get it to reset my search (set currentfilter to "" I guess?).

Comment: @kanpeki The input value **is** indeed set to "". `ViewBag.CurrentFilter` is the initial value in the input. `ViewBag` is used for passing the data from controller to `View`. You can't bind input value and post it back to controller.

Comment: @kanpeki are you new to MVC?

Comment: Yes, I am new to MVC. My search functionality follows this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application Before adding @type=search whenever I manually cleared the search box and pressed the button, the filter on the results would be cleared. Now, even if I press the button after clearing either manually or by pressing the X, the list remains unchanged (filtered using the last search term).

Comment: @kanpeki that's impossible. Something else is wrong. If the input is cleared, be it from the clear icon or manually or from javascript, whatever is there in the input will be submitted. You can put a breakpoint inside the controller and check what the value of `searchString` parameter is, after you clear the input.

Comment: you were right. the problem was that my button was of type button instead of submit. so in fact all worked well when pressing enter, but nothing did when pressing the search button. i just had mindlessly used enter most of the time...